# C# DateTimePicker - Bolded Dates?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

Is it possible to set a series of bolded dates for a DateTimePicker control in a C# Windows Forms application?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the standart DateTimePicker supports this but System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar has an AddBoldedDate() method. This way you can achieve what you desire.